# How to map Json Object with Hyphen to Java Object

Tags: java, json

We are integrating Restful webservice in existing application which uses IBM Websphere application server(RAD 7) and compiler is 5.0.

Now i have a situation where i am getting json data attribute with -. (my-name).
I am using jackson json api (using jersey jar files 1.2 as it is Java 5) to map json data to java objects.

Tried using `@JsonProperty` to get the corresponding JSON property. Object is getting initialized but property value is null.

```
class Person {

    @JsonProperty("first-name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last-name")
    private String lastName;

}
```

No exception but firstname and lastname value is null or empty.

Comment: Post your code, as code. Details matter. The code matters.

Comment: You can use PropertyNamingStrategy as suggested in jackson javadocs here: [Property Naming Strategy](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html).

Answer (score 0):

The @JsonProperty do the job, I have the same issue that you're had and using the annotation resolved it.